# How can I parse content of entered URL?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I need to parse content type of typed URL:

1. if it's an image then do something.
2. if it's a web page then scan this page for images and fill array with images' SRC attributes (and order it by size).

How can i do this using only JS?
How can i do this using only ASP.NET and C#?

Comment: You want to do it ONLY with Javascript and ONLY with c#????

Comment: You should get the headers, after that everything is easy. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/220231/accessing-http-headers-in-javascript

Comment: @Shoban
Yes. 

java script: you have a string (i.e. url). You must parse it and fill Array.


c#: you have a string (i.e. url). You must parse it and fill ArrayList.

Answer (score 0):

You can't if the URL is an image for sure. Either you go for `url.match( /\.jpg|\.gif|\.png/ ) === nil` (and other extensions, of course), or you make a `GET` call to the URL and look and the Content-Type in the response header.

Answer (score 0):

i'm not familiar with java but try this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/urls/urlInfo.html

Comment: Oops didnt see you wanted just JS!

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you can do it in C# (by actually making a request and inspecting the content type of the response):

```
    public static bool IsImage(string url)
    {
        WebRequest req = HttpWebRequest.Create(url);

        try
        {
            WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            return resp.ContentType.StartsWith("image");
        }
        catch { }

        return false;
    }
```